# unix fs permissions on windows node module

Tags: node.js, windows, unix, npm

Is there a node module that preserves unix fs permissions on windows machines? I have a .sh that I move around on a Windows machine that might transfer over to a Unix machine. Unix 'execute' permission does not transfer to Windows. Is there a way that I could fake those permissions?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. You usually do npm install on every machine you want node modules to be installed on. So transferring files isn't necessary. And if you want to copy files to production server, doing it from different platform (windows -> linux) is a very bad idea (native modules). So use Virtualbox on windows and do final preparation and testing on platform as close as possible to your production.

Comment: I have an nwjs app. I have a script that needs to run on a Mac or linux. It needs to be sent from a windows computer to a Mac or Linux computer because Windows users need to send a cross-platform app to Mac users.